# How to value this property

Tags: angular

How can I set the value to openUri ?
What is this called so I can learn more?

```
openUri?: ((uri: string) => void);
```

I tried...but get errors

```
  openUri: " https://blahblah"
```

Comment: Question is not clear :)

Comment: Add more description, Is `openUri` part of any class or object?

Comment: It's part of a class. I'm trying to set the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set openUri, try to use next:

```
openUri: string;

setOpenUri(uri: string): void {
   this.openUri = uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are combining typecasting and assigning value both.

exact code would be -

```
  openUri: string = "https://blahblah";
```

In typescript you can define type of variable followed by `:` and in order to assign value to that variable you need to use `=` operator.

Assigning a value in the constructor or `ngOnInit` is recommended instead of at the time of declaration.